# testing whether non-integer number is in range [a,b) - or [a,b], (a,b), (a,b]

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.1

What's the idiomatic way to achieve the below without reproducing the expression yielding the non-integer value (in my real case the value is computed as a percentage following a lengthy query which I don't want to reproduce):

```
SELECT * FROM SomeTable WHERE 1/100.0 >0 AND 1/100.0<=0.5
```

I am interested in a generalized pattern that can accommodate all type of boundaries: [], [), (] and ().

Comment: Your code really doesn't make sense.  I'm going to assume that you want that expression in the `where` clause, not the `select` clause.

Comment: @GordonLinoff you are right; I updated the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to rewrite the expression, then use a subquery:

```
select t.*
from (select 1/100.0 as x
      . . .
     ) t
where x > 0 and x <= 0.5
```

For the special case of equality as both nds, then you can use `between`:

```
where 1/100.0 between 0 and 0.5
```

Answer (score 0):

You can construct [the range](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/rangetypes.html) and check whether it contains your value:

```
SELECT * FROM SomeTable WHERE numrange(0,0.5,'(]') @> 1/100.0;
```

Comment: it appears that this is not available in PostgreSQL 9.1

Comment: Sorry for not looking at your tags, indeed, they appeared in 9.2 first.